# Beamer with Powerpoint title page in LyX

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning, lyx

I want to use `beamer` (`Madrid` style) for a presentation I'm giving next week, but I am forced to use the institutional title page.

That means that the whole background is filled by an image and the title itself cannot be in a coloured box.

In the worst case I will have to `pdftk` the title page onto the presentation, but I'm sure there must be a way to force LaTeX to do it.

I've tried using a `PlainFrame` with a `TitleGraphic`, but

- I can't get the image to stretch across the whole page
- the title itself will still be in a coloured box

Any ideas???

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [StackOverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to suppress the coloured box for the title, you'll need a redefinition of the `title page` template defined by the `default` inner theme used by `Madrid`.

To suppress the footline from the titlepage, you can use the `plain` option for the frame.

To include the image, you can set the `background canvas` template, using a standard `\includegraphics` (of course, instead of `papiro`, use one of your own images) command.

To keep all these changes local, you can use the grouping mechanism.

A little example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytitlepage}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\title{A Modified Beamer Theme}
\subtitle{Background image and no special decorations}
\author{The Author}
\institute{The Institute}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{papiro}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\endgroup

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A regular frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant! Works like a treat.